# Excel Scenario Manager

Tags: microsoft-excel

I can't figure out how to create a "what-if" summary by using 2 cells for each scenario. For example, there is a $1,000 loan with payments of $50,$100,$150 and a $2000 loan with payments of $100,$150,$250, the interest rate is 10%.How can I use the scenario manager to create a summary showing different payback lengths and total amount paid?

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple to do *without* using the Scenario Manager.  You need the NPER() function, which calculates the number of payments required to pay off a loan at a specified interest rate.  See Excel Help for a detailed explanation.  Here is a table of the results using the values you specified:

[image]

Columns A,B and C hold the various principals, payments and interest rate.  To calculate the number of payments, type this in D2 and fill down:

```
=NPER(C2/12,-B2,A2,0,1)
```

The interest rate needs to be per month, so the annual interest rate (10%) is divided by 12. A2 and B2 hold the principal amount (or present value) and payment.  The payment needs to be entered as a negative number here because the principal is decreasing.  The 0 specifies that the final amount (or future value) is zero, and the 1 specifies that the payment is made at the start of the period, rather than the end.

The total amount paid is just the number of periods times the payment. Type this in E2 and fill down:

```
=B2*D2
```

If you really want to use the Scenario Manager here, you could follow the examples on [this help page.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-What-If-Analysis-22bffa5f-e891-4acc-bf7a-e4645c446fb4)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I wonder how you calculated the total payments. Is there a formula for total payments?@Bandersnatch

Comment: Do you mean the total *number* of payments or the total amount paid? There's one payment in each period, so the number of payments is the same as the number of periods. In this case, a period is one month. The total amount paid is the number of payments times the amount of each payment. Column B times column D.

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please see [this link](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)