# Using mathmatical equivalent of Excel PMT function to solve for number of years

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, equations

Thanks to this forum I understand the math equivalent to the PMT function is P = (Pv*R) / [1 - (1 + R)^(-n)], and it works well.  However, I'd like to solve for n given P, and my algebra is but a 50 year memory.

The reason is to find how many months it would take to payoff a credit card using various values for P.  I find this equation works well when compared to the 3 year payoff amount found on the credit card statement.  However, when I use the n value they give for paying only the minimum, I get a significantly lower P than the minimum value.  There's probably something I don't understand about credit card calculations, but even so I'd like to solve for n given P.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I commend you for digging into the PMT() function, but I'm not sure why you want to use the formula instead of the built-in function. Excel has a robust set of financial functions that are fairly easy to use.  I'll help with this tomorrow, but in the meantime, I suggest you look in Excel help and read about the built in financial function NPER(). There is also a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1226898/excel-scenario-manager/1228062#1228062) solved using NPER() that you might find helpful.

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to the NPER() function, I was unaware of it, and it certainly simplifies things.  I'm still curious, and for no other reason than that, how to algebraically rearrange the math equivalent of the PMT() function to solve for n.

Comment: Additionally, after reviewing your post and thinking about it, it dawned on me that I've set upon this quest due to a faulty understanding of what is meant by the minimum payment and the length of time required to pay off the debt using that amount.  I plugged the minimum payment amount shown on one statement into the PMT() function and came up with significantly fewer periods than the credit card company.  The error in thinking of course, was that the company refigures the minimum payment monthly and that amount decreases each month, hence the longer period by their calculations than by mine.

Comment: Finally, I still plan to pursue the equation that uses such a diminishing minimum amount to confirm the company's calculations, again if for no other reason than curiosity.  Thanks for your help and the links; all very helpful.

Comment: You're very welcome, and if you need some help solving the equation for n, I'll walk you through the algebra tomorrow.  I'll need to look up that relationship about log(a^b) = something or other...  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here’s how to solve the payment equation for n:

The first steps are just moving things from one side to the other:

```
P = (Pv*R) / (1-(1+R)^(-n))
(1-(1+R)^(-n)) = (Pv*R)/P
(1+R)^(-n) = 1-(Pv*R)/P
```

A number raised to a negative power is the reciprocal of the number raised to the positive power.  e.g. 10^(-2) =.01=1/100=1/10^(2).  So:

```
1/((1+R)^(n)) = 1-(Pv*R)/P
(1+R)^(n) = 1/(1-(Pv*R)/P)
```

Taking the logarithm of both sides gets n out of the exponent ––  log(a^b) = b*log(a):

```
n*ln(1+R) = ln(1/(1-(Pv*R)/P))
```

And dividing by ln(1+R) gives:

```
n = ln(1/(1-(Pv*R)/P))/ln(1+R)
```

Algebra is pretty far back for me, also, so I found a [financial page](http://financeformulas.net/Number-of-Periods-of-Annuity-from-Present-Value.html) with this formula.  And it looks like I got it right. :-)

*And*, comparing this formula to Excel's NPER() shows they give the same results:

[image]

Here I used `=NPER(C2/12,-B2,A2,0,0)` in D2 and `=LN(1/(1-(A2*C2/12)/B2))/LN(1+C2/12)` in E2.  The last 0 in the NPER() formula specifies that payments are due at the end of the period.  So obviously, that's what the formula assumes too.

If the interest rate is given as an annual rate (as it is here) it must be divided by 12 in the formula to get the monthly rate.

I hope this helps you out Bob, and best wishes.

Comment: This is just what I was looking for to solve for n - many thanks for your enlightenment and the effort that required.  I suppose I could've scoured the internet for the answer myself, but I bet I'd still be scouring, and would be for some time.  So thanks again.

Comment: BTW, does Microsoft publish the formulas behind their functions?

Comment: I don't think they do, but most shouldn't be hard to find.  Do you have something particular in mind? I was pondering how NPER() calculates n when the payment is made at the start of the period.  If you change the last 0 to 1 in NPER(), you get slightly different answers, like 21.8 instead of 22.0.

Comment: Yeah, I too experimented with the 0 and 1 in the NPER() function and saw the difference.  I would think MS would publish a book of formulas behind their functions, they could probably use the extra revenue :) -  maybe it's a proprietary matter, although I wouldn't think so since most if not all are, as you suggest, probably freely available.  At any rate, thanks again for the help, its been a pleasure, a fine example of a positive internet interaction!

Comment: Yes, very nice to meet you.